# Receiving the error "Couldn't find Product with id=5" when I click on view cart link in my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a "view cart" link which returns the following error when clicked:

> Couldn't find Product with id=5

My `products_controller.rb` file looks like this:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @products = Product.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @products }
    end
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    logger.debug("Event code is: #{params[:id]}")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @product }
    end
  end

  # GET /products/new
  # GET /products/new.json
  def new
    @product = Product.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @product }
    end
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(params[:product])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @product, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /products/1
  # PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
  def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def add_to_cart
    @products = cookies[:products]
    if @products.blank?
    @products = cookies[:products] = params[:id]
    else
      unless @products.include? params[:id]
        cookies[:products] = @products + '&&' + params[:id]
      end
    end
    redirect_to products_url
  end

  def remove_from_cart
    @current_products = cookies[:products]
    if @current_products.blank?
      redirect_to products_url
    else
      @current_products = @current_products.split("&&")
      @current_products.delete(params[:id])
      @current_products = @current_products.join("&&")
      cookies[:products] = @current_products
      redirect_to products_url
    end
  end

  def view_cart
    @products = cookies[:products].split("&&").map { |s| s.to_i }
  end
end
```

My view_cart.html.erb file looks like this:

```
<h1>Your Cart</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <% total = 0 %>
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= Product.find(product).name %></td>
    <td><%= Product.find(product).price %></td>
    <% total += Product.find(product).price %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

Total: <%= total %>
```

I am a Rails novice and would appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `find` since you already have all `@products`. You iterate over that collection with `each` and you can access each element attributes like that:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= product.name %></td>
    <td><%= product.price %></td>
    <% total += product.price %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

i.e. `product` in the block is already "found" :)

Comment: Thank you, Zozo. I made the change and now I receive the following error:  NoMethodError in Products#view_cart

Showing /home/randy/rubystack-1.9.3-29/projects/chap13_cart_app/app/views/products/view_cart.html.erb where line #14 raised:

undefined method `name' for 2:Fixnum
Extracted source (around line #14):

11:   <% total = 0 %>
12: <% @products.each do |product| %>
13:   <tr>
14:     <td><%= product.name %></td>
15:     <td><%= product.price %></td>
16:     <% total += product.price %>
17:   </tr>

Answer (score 0):

We've [done a cart implementation before](http://firststopcosmeticshop.herokuapp.com) (based on this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/119-session-based-model)):

[image]

(more explained below)...

---

## Fix

*Your* error stems from the fact you're trying to `find` a product which doesn't exist.

There are a lot of problems with your code (for example, using `cart` methods inside your `products` controller). The simple fix is as follows:

```
#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
   def cart_view
      @products = cart_contents
   end

   private

   def cart_contents
     ##Cart product ID's
     products = cookies[:products].split("&&").map { |s| s.to_i }

     ##Only proceed if user has products in cart 
     if (products && products != {})

         #Determine Quantities (if ID appears 2 times etc)
         quantities = Hash[products.uniq.map {|i| [i, products.count(i)]}]

         #Get products from DB
         products_array = Product.find(products.uniq)

         #Create Qty Array with "qty" attached
         products_new = {}
         products_array.each{
             |a| products_new[a] = {"qty" => quantities[a.id.to_s]}
         }

         #Output appended
         return products_new

      end
   end
end
```

This is code we use (explained further down page) and will basically give you an ActiveRecord *collection* for your view.

So you'll be able to use the following:

```
#app/views/products/view_cart.html.erb
<% @products.each do |product| %>
   <%= product.name %>
<% end %>
```

---

## Structure

As mentioned, we've implemented this before:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :cart, only: [:index, :create, :destroy]

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def cart_session
      @cart_session ||= CartSession.new(session)
   end
   helper_method :cart_session
end

#app/controllers/cart_controller.rb
class CartController < ApplicationController
    include ApplicationHelper

    #Index
    def index
        @items = cart_session.cart_contents
    end
    
    #Add
    def create
        session[:cart] ||={}
        products = session[:cart][:products]
        
        #If exists, add new, else create new variable
        if (products && products != {})
            session[:cart][:products] << params[:id]
        else
            session[:cart][:products] = Array(params[:id])
        end
        
        #Handle the request
        respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render json: cart_session.build_json }
            format.html { redirect_to cart_index_path }
        end
    end
    
    #Delete
    def destroy
        session[:cart] ||={}
        products = session[:cart][:products]
        id = params[:id]
        all = params[:all]

        #Is ID present?
        unless id.blank?
            unless all.blank?
                products.delete(params['id'])
            else
                products.delete_at(products.index(id) || products.length)
            end
        else
            products.delete
        end
        
        #Handle the request
        respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render json: cart_session.build_json }
            format.html { redirect_to cart_index_path }
        end
    end
end
```

The above gives you a `cart_session` method, which creates or invokes the `CartSession` model. This is just a class which puts all the user's "cart items" in a session.

The important thing to note is that because the `cart` controller is separate to the `products` controller, it allows you to split your code into a [resourceful](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) structure.

It also means you keep your code extremely lean - the *only* overhead will be a small array of product IDs kept in a session variable. No `ActiveRecord` or anything...

```
#app/models/cart_session.rb
class CartSession

    #Initalize Cart Session
    def initialize(session)
        @session = session
        @session[:cart] ||= {}
    end
    
    #Cart Count
    def cart_count
        if (@session[:cart][:products] && @session[:cart][:products] != {})
            @session[:cart][:products].count
        else
            0
        end
    end
    
    #Cart Contents
    def cart_contents
        products = @session[:cart][:products]

        if (products && products != {})
        
            #Determine Quantities
            quantities = Hash[products.uniq.map {|i| [i, products.count(i)]}]
            
            #Get products from DB
            products_array = Product.find(products.uniq)
            
            #Create Qty Array
            products_new = {}
            products_array.each{
                |a| products_new[a] = {"qty" => quantities[a.id.to_s]}
            }
            
            #Output appended
            return products_new
            
        end

    end
        
    #Qty & Price Count
    def subtotal
        products = cart_contents
        
        #Get subtotal of the cart items
        subtotal = 0
        unless products.blank?
            products.each do |a|
                subtotal += (a[0]["price"].to_f * a[1]["qty"].to_f)
            end
        end
        
        return subtotal
        
    end
    
    #Build Hash For ActiveMerchant
    def build_order
    
        #Take cart objects & add them to items hash
        products = cart_contents
        
        @order = []
        products.each do |product|
            @order << {name: product[0].name, quantity: product[1]["qty"], amount: (product[0].price * 100).to_i }
        end
        
        return @order
    end
    
    #Build JSON Requests
    def build_json
        session = @session[:cart][:products]
        json = {:subtotal => self.subtotal.to_f.round(2), :qty => self.cart_count, :items => Hash[session.uniq.map {|i| [i, session.count(i)]}]}
        return json
    end

end
```

This allows you to use the following:

```
#app/views/cart/index.html.erb
<% @items.each do |item| %>
   <%= item.name %> #=> this will be the ActiveRecord "Product" record
<% end %>
```

You'll also be able to do the following:

```
#app/views/products/show.html.erb
<%= link_to "Add To Cart", cart_path(@product.id), method: :post %> #-> adds product to cart
```

The best thing about this method is that the `cart` functionality is split into its own controller & model. At the moment, you've broken the [*resourceful*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_resource) convention by including non-rest methods in your `products` controller.

You need to keep your `cart` functionality in its own controller, and products functionality in its own controller. The above achieves this.